# Marshaling an Object to XML when Object has XML within it (JAXB)

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

I have a simple Object that I'm trying to marshal into XML:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "MyObject")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyObject {

  @XmlElement(name = "ResultsAsString")
  private String resultsAsString;

  @XmlElement(name = "ResultsAsXml")
  private String resultsAsXml;
}
```

In the second field I'm passing in some xml. However when I try marshaling the object using JAXB:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyObject.class);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
```

The xml within the second field comes out garbled. All the "<" tags get replaced with "&lt" and the quotes replaced with "&quot" but all the ">" tags stay the same. Is there a reason why JAXB encodes part of the XML but leaves the ">" character unencoded? This is breaking functionality late on in my code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I used garbled out of frustration. Is there a reason but it encodes parts of the string but not others? I wouldn't mind if it encoded everything but currently it's encoding some parts and leaving other parts untouched which is breaking other functionality later on.

Answer (score 0):

JAX-B doesn't know that your property `resultsAsXml` contains valid XML, so it handles it as plain text.

It has to escape `<` and `&` to create valid XML, see [Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.1 (Second Edition)](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#syntax):

> The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) must not appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. If they are needed elsewhere, they must be escaped using either numeric character references or the strings "`&amp;`" and "`&lt;`" respectively. The right angle bracket (>) may be represented using the string "`&gt;`", and must, for compatibility, be escaped using either "`&gt;`" or a character reference when it appears in the string "`]]>`" in content, when that string is not marking the end of a CDATA section.